# JSF 2.0, Bean Validation and labels

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

How can I show the field label in a JSF error message when bean validation is used?

```
<h:messages/>
<h:inputText label="Username" value="#{myBean.username}" />
...
```

```
public class MyBean {
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    ...
}
```

If no user name is submitted only "Must not be null" is shown and there is no field reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To display the concerned component's label in the error message define a new value for the property javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE in a resource bundle of the application like this:

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={1}: {0}
```

The placeholder `{0}` refers to the error message as created by the Bean Validation runtime, `{1}` refers to the component label. More information can be found in the [JSF 2 spec.](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314)  section 3.5.6.3.

Comment: Hm, for me it only works when this key is defined in a message-bundle. In a resource-bundle it has no effect.

Comment: The javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE is already in message bundel