# Include field name in error messages generated by annotated validators in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

It's very handy to use bean validation like `javax.validation.constraints.Size` in my Java code, such as:

```
@Size(min=1,max=30)protected String custName;
```

rather than the wordier equivalent embedded in the .xhtml page, such as:

```
<f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="30" />
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to get the field name to appear in the error message.  I can customize the message by adding the following entry to ValidationMessages.properties in the root of my source directory:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message={0} value is too long.
```

But no value gets substituted for {0}.  The upshot is that while the annotated validators work fine for simple pages where I can include a separate `<p:message />` for each form field, they don't work so well for a more complex (e.g. tabbed) form where I need to group my messages at the top of the page.  Is there any workaround for this, or is my only reasonable choice to use the JSF validators?

Answer (score 4):

The `{0}` is represented by the `label` attribute of the input component in the view side, which defaults to client ID when unspecified.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.customer.name}" label="Customer name">
```

You also need to override the JSF's default format for bean validator messages. You need to add the following entry to JSF message bundle as specified in `<message-bundle>` of `faces-config.xml`:

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE = {1} {0}
```

In this specific entry, the `{1}` will be the label of the JSF input component and `{0}` will be the message of the bean validator.

Comment: I do specify the label attribute - still doesn't get the field name through.  (I'm using PrimeFaces 3.0.1 inputText rather than h:inputText, but it doesn't seem like that should matter).

Comment: It sounds good, and I even found a couple other references to the same solution ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803536/jsf-2-0-bean-validation-and-labels and https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1009538 ), but no joy for me.